# Border only showing on device

Tags: java, android, xml

My app is showing a border around each view (view background) that I do not want there. I have set the parent layout to have a 0dp margin and 0dp padding and in the Android Studio preview there is no border.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/list_form_1"
android:background="#f7f1b9"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp">
```

Comment: There's a developer setting that shows borders.  Are you sure you don't have it on by mistake?

Comment: can you upload some screenshots maybe ?

Comment: style on manifest perhaps?